# How can I solve "bash: src/examples/voice/assistant_grpc_demo.py: No such file or directory" while installing Google Assistant SDK on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, robotics

I am trying to setup google assistant SDK on my raspberry `pi`. I followed this link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QP9buT2RcCg&t=839s

But at the last item, when I entered the command
`src/examples/voice/assistant_grpc_demo.py` There is an error:

> bash: src/examples/voice/assistant_grpc_demo.py: No such file or directory

I don't have enough knowledge about it. My science fair is running and I'm stopped for this problem.

Comment: `src/examples/voice/assistant_grpc_demo.py` file is there ? `ls src/examples/voice/assistant_grpc_demo.py` to make sure that file is there or not

Comment: no, it is missing from there.

Comment: what  can i do ? @hansolo

Comment: You'd have to download it somehow. I'm am not familiar with the project

Comment: How can I download it?